# gcc ARM compiler Storing a string in .text section

Tags: gcc, arm

I am trying to write a PIC binary which is patched later into another program. The problem is that the binary includes data in its *.rodata*

Is it possible to compile the program with strings in the *.text* section?
I have tried using `const char[]` but that still compiles with data in the *.rodata* section.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a linker script to place the sections appropriately.  For instance,

```
  .text : { *.o(.text .rodata) }
```

Will take **input** sections *.text* and *.rodata* (from all object or *dot O* file) and put them in the **output** section *.text*.